# White space when view scroll up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have three layout in one xml file. I am setting the visibility `GONE` of the first layout when user clicks on the cancel button on the first layout. So below two layout will move to up. Like below image:

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**[image: After]

Below is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@color/welcomeAreaColor"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closeWelcomeTextButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/close_icons"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDesc"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_welcomeTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="-15dp"
            android:text="@string/welCome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_welcomeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/welcometextData"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="17dp" >


  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_betaTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/frag1_betaTitle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_betaText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/frag1_betaText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
 </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/navyBlue"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_buildYourTeam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/frag1_buildYourTeam"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag1_buildYourTeamText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/frag1_buildYourTeamText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date_display"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/belowCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/belowLogoText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/benifits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/benifits"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/belowBenifitsRefrall1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/referralOne"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/belowBenifitsRefrall2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/referralTwo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as what i got from your question is that you are struggling with the space at the bottom of the page which is coming as soon as you close the welcome message.

If this is your problem then i have a quick solution.

Make your parent layout background color same as bottom layout color and so if these is no child layout then it will display same color which is in your bottom layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/navyBlue"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: yes you are right this is what i want to make. let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your manifest file in activity tag:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```